# Can't upgrade to Angular 13

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project which I am trying to upgrade from Angular 11 to Angular 13. I followed the instructions [here](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-12.0) and [here](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=12.0-13.0). So basically I upgraded first to 12 and then to 13. Now when I try to build it I get this error `$ ng build ux-prod --aot=true --buildOptimizer=true --sourceMap=false --configuration production=true An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production=true' is not set in the workspace.`
This is my `angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
...
    "ux-prod": {
      "root": "src_prod/main",
      "sourceRoot": "src_prod/main/webapp/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
...
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ux:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js",
            "host": "localhost"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ux:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
...
      }
    }
  },
...
}
```

I looked at other posts that describe a similar issue and all of them mention the prod config not being present. But in my case i see it under the `"serve"` node. How do i fix it? The file `angular.json` has not been changed manually. It was changed by the scripts I ran. Should I manually edit it? What is missing?

Comment: Maybe you should only set `--configuration production` (without the `=true` part). Or even `--configuration=production` could work.

Comment: Thank you @OctavianMărculescu. Both your suggestions worked. However. I get another error, probably unrelated to your fix: `Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined
[ERROR]     at extendFormats (/home/me/source/ux/node_modules/babel-loader/node_modules/ajv-keywords/keywords/_formatLimit.js:63:25)`. Working on it...